# AdMob Integration - close from AdMob

Tags: admob

I have used AdMob integration in my app. The add opens in Safari. Now how do i come back from the Ad to my app. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The advertiser decides whether the click opens up an in-app web browser or external web browser on iOS. The should open it up in the in-app browser, because there is no back button in the Safari app.

Answer (score 0):

In ios 9, there is a "Back to (App name)"